# Can't change spacing with titlesec in report class

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

so I know I should be able to change the spacing with this command:

> \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parksip}

But no matter how I change the values the spacing doesn't change at all. Could it be that it has something to do with the fact that I use explicit:

> \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

Or that my documentclass is report?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{2cm} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
   \fontsize{70}{110}\selectfont\thechapter}%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \hfill{\Huge#1}\\
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
   \mbox{}}%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \hfill{\LARGE#1}\\
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}


\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0cm}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\vspace{\parskip}}{\vspace{-\parskip}}
```

Then in the text I've used it like this:

```
This shows that there aren't many mutations.

\subsubsection*{YME1L1}
This gene had the following mutation:\\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\parskip` is not a command for issuing space, but a container for the value used. You perhaps want `\vspace{\parskip}` and `\vspace{-\parskip}`. Can you please show a minimal example of code?

Comment: Please add the code to your question, but what's necessary are the `titlesec` related settings, not how you call a subsubsection.

Comment: I think i have added all the relevant things

Comment: The value of `\parskip` is `0pt plus 0.1pt`; if you don't change it, there's nothing `\vspace{\parskip}` can do.

Comment: yeah okay, but even if I'd change it to \titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{-20cm}{-20cm} nothing happens

Comment: It's so weird, because I can fix it if I manually put \space{-2ex} before and after a \section{..} but it doesn't work when I do this titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{-20cm}{-20cm}.